# php upload files more than one at a time

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this piece of code `<input type="file" name="image_logo" id="image_logo"  />`
This one will select only one file when browsed.
Now there I have made another checkbox like this
`<input type="checkbox" name="multiple_upload" value="yes" > &nbsp; Do You want to upload multiple files at a time?`

Now if someone click on the checkbox I want he can select multiple files to upload. For multiple files select I have the code like this
`<input type="file" name="image_logo" id="image_logo" multiple />`

But here I want that if a user clicks on the checkbox then he will select multiple files at atime otherwise he will select only one file. So for that my code goes like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="multiple_upload" value="yes" >
 <?php if(isset($_POST['multiple_upload'])) {
  <input type="file" name="image_logo" id="image_logo" multiple />
 }
 else {
 <input type="file" name="image_logo" id="image_logo"  />
 }
```

But here the problem is as I have used `$_POST` then he can't select all the files on click instantly. I want that when user click on checkbox then he will instantly select multiple files at a time. He don't have to refresh the page.

If the user doesn't click on checkbox then he can't select multiple files at a time. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this so that user can make the action instantly? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: `multiple` doesn’t mean the user _has to_ upload more than one file, so why don’t you set that attribute in the first place and let them chose only one or multiple files as they wish …?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('input[name="multiple_upload"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'yes'){
        $('input[type="file"]').prop('multiple', true);
    }else{
        $('input[type="file"]').prop('multiple', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6DvdH/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="multiple_upload"]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#image_logo').attr('multiple', true);
        } else {
            $('#image_logo').removeAttr('multiple');
        }
    });
});
```